# flask showing error when using emit function

Tags: python

I am receiving data from a TCP server and I am passing it to client using websocket for which it is showing working outside of request context
The code is something like this

```
def recv(msg):
     data=msg
     emit('info',{'data': data})
```

and my html script code is

```
 <script type ='text/javascript'>
 var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domaiin + ':' + location.port)

 socket.on('info', function(msg){
         console.log(msg);
    });
```

But there is no output on the console.

Comment: Is `console/log` a typo or is this your actual code ? (should be `console.log`)

Comment: sorry it was a typo

Comment: Can you include more code, at least enough to reproduce the error? Your first example isn't even valid Python code.